# How to get the derivative

Tags: calculus

How do I find the derivative of $\displaystyle \frac{1+4\cos x}{2 \sqrt{x+4\sin x}}?$

So I got this as my answer: 
$$\frac{(4 \cos x+1)^2}{4\sqrt{4 \sin x+x}}-2 \sin x \sqrt{4\sin x+x}$$

does this look correct?

Comment: @Nick Yes it is!

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE, Please learn [how to type math](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on this site using $\LaTeX$ and also read the [help](http://math.stackexchange.com/help)    section regarding [asking questions](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Answer (score 2):

To avoid that nasty quotient rule
(and throwing away that "$2$"),

$\begin{array}\\
\left(\frac{1+4\cos x}{ \sqrt{x+4\sin x}}\right)'
&=\left((1+4\cos x)(x+4\sin x)^{-1/2}\right)'\\
&=(1+4\cos x)\left((x+4\sin x)^{-1/2}\right)'
+(1+4\cos x)'(x+4\sin x)^{-1/2}\\
&=(1+4\cos x)\left((-1/2)((x+4\sin x)'(x+4\sin x)^{-3/2}\right)
+(-4\sin x)(x+4\sin x)^{-1/2}\\
&=(1+4\cos x)\left((-1/2)((1+4\cos x)(x+4\sin x)^{-3/2}\right)
+(-4\sin x)(x+4\sin x)^{-1/2}\\
&=\frac{(-1/2)(1+4\cos x)^2
+(-4\sin x)(x+4\sin x)}{(x+4\sin x)^{3/2}}\\
&=-\frac{(1+4\cos x)^2
+(8\sin x)(x+4\sin x)}{2(x+4\sin x)^{3/2}}\\
&=-\frac{1+8\cos x+16\cos^2 x
+8x\sin x+32\sin^2 x}{2(x+4\sin x)^{3/2}}\\
&=-\frac{1+8\cos x+16
+8x\sin x+16\sin^2 x}{2(x+4\sin x)^{3/2}}\\
\end{array}
$

Or,
looking at 
Przemysław Scherwentke's
marvelous suggestion,
since
$(x+4\sin x)'
=1+4\cos x
$
and
$(f'f^{-1/2})'
=f'' f^{-1/2}+f'(-1/2)f'f^{-3/2}
=\dfrac{f'' f+(-1/2)f'^2}{f^{-3/2}}
$,
if
$f(x)
=x+4\sin x
$,
$f'(x)
=1+4\cos x
$
and
$f''(x)
=-4\sin x
$
we get

$\begin{array}\\
(f'f^{-1/2})'
&=f'' f^{-1/2}+f'(-1/2)f'f^{-3/2}\\
&=\dfrac{(-4\sin x) (x+4\sin x)+(-1/2)(1+4\cos x)^2}{(x+4\sin x)^{3/2}}\\
&=\dfrac{-4x\sin x-16\sin^2 x)-(1/2)(1+8\cos x+16\cos^2x}{(x+4\sin x)^{3/2}}\\
&=-\dfrac{8x\sin x+32\sin^2 x+1+8\cos x+16\cos^2x}{(x+4\sin x)^{3/2}}\\
\end{array}
$.

By a miracle,
the two results are the same.

Comment: It can be noted that $n\sin^2 x + n\cos^2 x = n$

Answer (score 1):

It cries: "I am $\sqrt{x+4\sin x}$ up to a multiplicative constant!"

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: @Nick Usage of this remark to simplify calculations is shown in marty cohen's solution.

Comment: His solution looks no different than mine. But I still don't understand your hint. If I am to guess, then I would say that you are remarking on the fact that the given function essentially contains $x + 4\sin x$ and its derivative in the form $\frac{u'}{2\sqrt{u}}$. But what do mean by a "multiplicative constant"? And why $\sqrt{x + 4\sin x}$ ?

Comment: This person previously posted a question asking for the derivative of $\sqrt{x + 4\sin x}$, which is the function above. Now she's just rewording it to ask for the second derivative.

Comment: @Dylan Oh? then, it seems that the answers on this page may be unsuitable for Maggie considering that she is struggling on the fundamentals. Hopefully, she'll pull through.

Answer (score 1):

Troubled by the quotient rule? Then it *might* be helpful to rewrite your question:

$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\left(\frac{1 + 4\cos x}{2\sqrt{x+ 4\sin x}}\right) = \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}(1 + 4\cos x)(x + 4\sin x)^{-1/2}\right)$$

Now, just use the product rule accompanied by the chain rule.
Try it out!

---

Here's how I would proceed:

Let $u = x + 4\sin x \implies u' = 1 + 4\cos x$

Substituting, your question now becomes:
$$\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} (u') \cdot (u^{-1/2})\right)\\
= \frac{1}{2}\left(u''\cdot u^{-1/2}\ +\  u'\cdot \Big(-\frac{1}{2}u^{-3/2}\cdot u'\Big)\right)\\
= \frac{u''}{2\cdot u^{1/2}} - \frac{u'}{4\cdot u^{3/2}}\\
= \frac{2u\cdot u'' \ - \ u'}{4\cdot u^{3/2}}$$

where $u'' = \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\left( 1 + 4\cos x\right) =  - 4\sin x$

Now, you would get the same result if you had directly applied the quotient rule (which is a special case of the product rule). You can infact derive the quotient rule by applying the product rule to $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} f(x)\cdot\Big(g(x)\Big)^{-1         }$ . I leave this as an exercise to you but in order to convince yourself further, redo the question directly using the quotient rule       :

$$ \frac{ \mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} \left(\frac{u'}{2\sqrt{u}}\right) = \frac{1}{2}\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\left(\frac{u'}{u^{1/2}}\right) = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{u''\sqrt u \ - \ u'\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{u}}}{u}\right) \equiv \frac{2u\cdot u'' \ - \ u'}{4\cdot u^{3/2}}$$

Alternatively, set $ y = \frac{u'}{2\sqrt u} \implies 2y\sqrt u = u'$ and then differentiate and solve to get $y'$

Answer (score 0):

Do it in order
$$\frac{\frac{d}{dx}(1+4\cos x)2\sqrt{x+4\sin x} -\frac{d}{dx}(2\sqrt{x+4\sin x})(1+4\cos x)}{4(x+4\sin x)}.$$

Solve the derivatives one by one and then replace in the big fraction. Remember to use the chain rule!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you will need to use the quotient rule and the chain rule to solve this. The quotient rule tells us that $$\left[\frac{1+4\cos x}{2 \sqrt{x+4\sin x}}\right]' = \frac{[1+4\cos(x)]'2 \sqrt{x+4\sin x}-\left(1+4\cos(x)\right)\left[2 \sqrt{x+4\sin(x)}\right]'}{\left(2 \sqrt{x+4\sin(x)}\right)^2}$$ and to evaluate $\left[2 \sqrt{x+4\sin(x)}\right]'$ you need the chain rule. You should get $$\left[2 \sqrt{x+4\sin(x)}\right]' = \frac{2}{2\sqrt{x+4\sin(x)}} \cdot \left(1+4\cos(x)\right) \\ =  \frac{1+4\cos(x)}{\sqrt{x+4\sin(x)}}$$ Now you can plug this expression into the one above to get $$ \frac{[1+4\cos(x)]'2 \sqrt{x+4\sin x}-\left(1+4\cos(x)\right) \frac{1+4\cos(x)}{\sqrt{x+4\sin(x)}}}{\left(2 \sqrt{x+4\sin(x)}\right)^2}$$ There is still a tremendous amount of simplification to be done, but it's mostly algebra.

Comment: Alternatively, implicitly differentiate $2y^{2}(x + 4\sin x) = (1 + 4\cos x)^{2}.$